# Spark / Hdfs / Hdfs-client compatibility

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm running a hdfs cluster based hdfs version 2.9.1.
This cluster is used by Spark (built against hdfs client 2.9.1) and standalone scala/java programs that use hdfs-client 2.9.1 as well.

I want to gradually upgrade the setup to hdfs 3.*.* without breaking too much.
I haven't found an approachable guide on compatibility between hdfs server and hdfs client.

Is it possible to upgrade first hdfs client and then hdfs file system?
Or the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on API you use.
Hadoop classes and interfaces are classified [1](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/InterfaceClassification.html) with annotations, either `Stable`, `Evolving`, `Unstable`, `Deprecated`.

`Stable` API is safe to use, since it's not expected to be removed until Hadoop 4.0.0 [2](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Compatibility.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Assuming I'm using only stable API, what should I update first: hadoop client libraries or hadoop file system?

Comment: @simpadjo I suggest to use a testing environment in order to put together an upgrade plan. You can easily compile you application with different version of libraries, so you can start with that. I believe upgrading server-side would be more resource consuming

Comment: Idk, perhaps I formulated my question in a bad way. I basically want do perform a rolling upgrade of the system which consists of dozens of components and maintained by a handful of people. Of course, creating a fresh environment is always an option but that's the worst case scenario.